# Не получается исключить страницы в woprdpress

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

У меня подгружались похожие записи. Я добавил ещё и страницы.

```
'post_type' => array('post','page')
```

Стали выводиться все страницы в том числе и ненужные, такие как "контакты" и прочее.
Я добавил

```
'exclude' => '12,14,21,23'
```

, но никакого толку они так же подгружаются, не исключаются.

В чём ошибка? почему не работает exclude?

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_related_posts', 'get_related_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_related_posts', 'get_related_posts');
function get_related_posts() {
    $post__not_in = $_POST['post__not_in'];
    $category__in = $_POST['category__in'];
    $args = array('post__not_in' => $post__not_in, 'category__in' =>    $category__in, 'posts_per_page' => 3, 
'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'rand', 
'post_type' => array('post','page'), 'exclude'  => array(12,14,21,23));
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <div class="related-posts-block clearfix">
        <?php
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="related-post" data-post-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                        the_post_thumbnail('s320x160');
                    } else { ?>
                        <img src="//placehold.it/250x125">
                        <?php
                    } ?>
                    <div class="related-post-title">
                        <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
endif;
die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя из [документации](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) параметра `exclude` там нет. Но есть параметр `post__not_in`, который работает схожим образом:

```
// This will NOT work
$exclude_ids = '1,2,3';
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => array( $exclude_ids ) ) );

// This WILL work
$exclude_ids = array( 1, 2, 3 );
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => $exclude_ids ) );
```

Comment: И как мне его прописать?

Comment: В смысле? Так же как и exclude

Comment: Не увидел что он уже у вас есть, попробуйте добавить в массив `$_POST['post__not_in']` - `$post__not_in = array_merge($_POST['post__not_in'], [12,14,21,23])`

Comment: с этим вообще не подгружаются